# Umbraco ContentPicker property is setting complete URL not relative

Tags: umbraco, umbraco7

We have a property that uses the obsolete `Umbraco.ContentPickerAlias`

On our development sites, that are also multiple site (each site has a URL set in the Cultures and Hostnames), the property returns a relative URL (eg: /home/) but on our test sites, the property is returning a full URL (eg: https://site1.com/home/)

We have code that assumes the URL will be relative (which I will remedy)

Is there a setting on the site/umbracoSettings.config that is causing this property behaviour?

Comment: Can you post some more details of your code and ss from CMS?

Answer (score 0):

This issue was not related to the property itself, but that if a site has a domain in the Cultures and Hostnames that is not equal to the domain itself, each page's link will be absolute rather than relative. The ContentPicker is merely returning the value for the chosen element's link